# How to pass a search query parameter to elastic search url

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I pass the query below on the url using a GET method to make a call to elastic search. Since it's a get I can't pass a body..

```
GET ContentStoreBiblio/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "_id": {id}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To get a Elasticsearch object with specific Id, there's another way using: `/ContentStoreBiblio/<mapping type name>/<id>`.  This is for versions lower than 7. For 7 and onwards I think mapping type is not required.

Comment: You only need to make a query on the `_id` field ?